# ANTLR not recognizing special characters tokens

Tags: java, token, antlr, lexer

I am writing the grammar rules for complex logic operations and I am stuck with the tokens. My lexer grammar goes like this:

```
VAR     : 'A'..'Z';
WS      : [ \t\r]+ -> skip;
NL      : '\n';
TRUE    : '1';
FALSE   : '0';

AND     : '∧';
NAND    : '⊼';
OR      : '∨';
XOR     : '⊻';
NOR     : '⊽';
IMPLIES : '⇒';
BICOND  : '⇔';
NEGATE  : '¬';
EQUIV   : '≡';
EQ      : '=';
LPAR    : '(';
RPAR    : ')';
```

As you can see I am using special symbols for every operation (that should be recognized). The problem is that when I test the parser and I try to visit the tree it gives me the next error:

```
line 1:1 token recognition error at: '⊼'
```

It gives me the same error using every operator.
I can tell that the problem is related to encoding because if I replace the symbols for more common ones it visits the tree and gives me the correct result of the operation.

I am using ANTLR in Java.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the solution. As I thought it was an encoding problem, I just had to set the tool-option **encoding** in the grammar file as **UTF-8**.

Thank you anyways!